# why is like that, why it's varying its length, when I use $_POST['area'] = $_SESSION['area']?

Tags: php, session, post

```
input = All
$_SESSION['area'] = $_POST['area'].'<br>'//All 

var_dump($_SESSION['area'];//string(7) 

var_dump($_POST['area']);//string(3)
```

Why is like that, why it's varying its length!?

Comment: Print your actual results here.

Comment: What is `input = All` it is definitely not PHP

Comment: do you have a  `session_start()` in that code somewhere

Comment: **Facinated** to know why 2 people thought this question was worth an UpVote. Maybe they should read the tooltop for the Up Arrow

Comment: yes i have a session start and i am getting 'All' from a input box. @Riggs try and give me solution, that's the perfect way to give a answer i think.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could this be a UTF-8 encoding thing?

Comment: No.  @RiggsFolly

Comment: No it's not? or No idea?

Comment: Did you forget to close the bracket in line `var_dump($_SESSION['area'];//string(7) ` ?

Comment: No that's not an issue @ravi, that's just a typo error

Comment: Please Edit your correct question Because there is lot's of a typo error in your question And I tested in local it is working fine and showing correct string length. @SureshSarika

Comment: you understood my question that's enough @nawin. thanks for your effort, i am trying to get the reason for it, if i get to know i will give you the answer.

Comment: @SureshSarika That was by far the most disrespectful comment you could make to someone on the internet attempting to help you. Maybe you should help the people trying to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['area']` is three characters long.

`'<br>'` is four characters long.

`.` appends two strings.

`$_POST['area'].'<br>'` appends a four letter string to a three letter string.

3 + 4 = 7